# Key generation requirements for TLS ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256

Tags: node.js, cryptography, openssl

I was wondering if there are minimum key-generation requirements for ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 and ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256?  I am trying to get a TLS client and server using one of the above algorithms to connect to each other and keep receiving 'no shared cipher errors'.  I created a CA for signing client and server certs, and attempted connecting with just openssl and also in node.js. I am running the client and server on localhost (127.0.0.1) to eliminate any other possible problems.

Here is what I have done so far:

CA key pair creation:

```
  $ openssl genrsa -out ca-key.pem 4096
  $ openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca-key.pem -out ca-cert.pem
```

Server / client key pair creation:

```
  $ openssl genrsa -out server-key.pem 4096
  $ openssl req -new -key server-key.pem -out server-csr.pem
  $ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server-csr.pem -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out server-cert.pem 

  $ openssl genrsa -out client-key.pem 4096
  $ openssl req -new -key client-key.pem -out client-csr.pem
  $ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in client-csr.pem -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 02 -out client-cert.pem
```

I was originally attempting to connect to a node.js server from the command line (tls.createServer() with options: ciphers: 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256'), but to eliminate node suspicion I fell back to openssl for both client and server creation.

The following commands CORRECTLY connect for client and server and states it is using a cipher of "New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384":

```
$ openssl s_server -accept 8888 -cert server-cert.pem -key server-key.pem -pass stdin -CAfile ca-cert.pem  -state
<password entered here>

$ openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8888 -cert client-cert.pem -key client-key.pem -pass stdin -CAfile ca-cert.pem -state
<password entered here>
```

With the shared cipher information as follows:

```
Shared ciphers:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-R
SA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES2
56-SHA:SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384
:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-A
ES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA:ECD
H-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH
-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384
:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES
-CBC3-SHA:SRP-DSS-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA
:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA2
56:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:SRP-DSS
-AES-128-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

The following commands do NOT work when I specify a cipher on the server, or the client and server. Note that the ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 cipher is listed as shared in the above list.

```
$ openssl s_server -accept 8888 -cert server-cert.pem -key server-key.pem -pass stdin -CAfile ca-cert.pem -cipher ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
<password entered here>

<< Server output after client connection attempt >>
Using default temp DH parameters
Using default temp ECDH parameters
ACCEPT
ERROR
2674688:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher:s3_srvr.c:1353:
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
ACCEPT


$ openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8888 -cert client-cert.pem -key client-key.pem -pass stdin -CAfile ca-cert.pem -cipher ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
<password entered here>

<<client output after connection attempt>>
CONNECTED(00000003)
2674688:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:708:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 166 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of openssl are you using? openssl version

Comment: I'm using OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012

Comment: Also be sure to use a "named curve". For the details, see [Elliptic Curve Cryptography | Named Curves](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography#Named_Curves) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are making the wrong kind of key with

```
 openssl genrsa -out ca-key.pem 4096
```

You need to use [ecparam](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ecparam.html)

```
openssl ecparam -name secp521r1 -out ca-key.pem -genkey
```

and

```
openssl ecparam -name secp521r1 -out client-key.pem -genkey
```

`genrsa` generates an RSA key that, when used with ECDHE, authenticates the Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman key Exchange (ECDHE).

The ECDSA in  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256  means you need the  Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm to authenticate that key. Because you don't have those kind of  keys, the command fails. However,  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 works because it uses RSA keys which you have.

You are getting sha384 because openssl picks the strongest cipher suite and all things being equal sha384 is better than sha256. You can override this, and it looks like you did so with `--cipher`.

Note you may want to use a different curve. You can get the full list with

```
openssl ecparam -list_curves
```

Out of curiosity, why that specific cipher suite?  ECDHE and ECDSA are state of the art, but sha256 is just standard, and well AES 128 is certainly good enough, people tend to use 256 if they are being as cautious as the ECDHE and ECDSA stuff implies.

Comment: Thanks! That put me on the right track. :D  I picked those cipher suites to match [RFC 6460](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6460), and should have picked up on the 'Acceptable Curves' section that specifies using secp256r1 or secp384r1 respectively. For further reference I will post the commands I used in openssl. I also had to set up the demoCA directory and its contents as listed in the [examples](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ca.html#EXAMPLES) section.

Comment: I used this [Elliptic Curve CA guide](http://this.is.thoughtcrime.org.nz/elliptic-curve-ca-guide) for openssl examples to sign the keys. I had to create the directories mentioned in [CA examples](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ca.html#EXAMPLES) before I could sign anything. I used the following commands to test:

`openssl s_server -accept 8888 -cert server.cert -key 
server.key -pass stdin -CAfile ca.cert -cipher ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256` and 
`openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8888 -cert client.cert -key client.key -pass stdin -CAfile ca.cert -cipher ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256`

Comment: Nitpick: for ECDHE-ECDSA the server key, and the client key if client auth is used as here, must be ECC. The CA key is not required to be ECC, RSA still works. But good practice says any CA key should be at least as *strong* as the keys signed under it, so (minimal) ECC 256 requires RSA>=3072 using NIST's equivalences.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Nitpick^2:  For ECDHE-ECDSA cipher, the client key/cert can be RSA. For RSA cipher, the client key/cert can be ECDSA. The verification phase *at server* only expects to arrive at a trusted certificate, not necessarily to use the same cipher. The verification phase *at client* is more stringent, as you described.

Comment: @kubanczyk: you're right; I must have been hallucinating that day. Client EE cert&key type is constrained only by *CertificateRequest*. And to add a wrinkle: in TLS1.2, which is used more today than it was in 2012, *chain/CA* certs from server are constrained by *signature_algorithms* in ClientHello, and from client by a similar field in CertificateRequest, but in both cases *not* by ciphersuite.