# Using Node JS TLS passphrase and cipher options when creating a server and client using elliptic curve keys (no shared cipher suites error)

Tags: node.js, cryptography, openssl, ssl, elliptic-curve

In relation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185110/key-generation-requirements-for-tls-ecdhe-ecdsa-aes128-gcm-sha256), I am trying to start a TLS server in node.js to reflect the one I created in OpenSSL. I have tested the client and server using OpenSSL from the command line and they successfully make a connection. When I try to port the server to node.js (and still connect to it with an OpenSSL client), I receive a 'no shared cipher' error. I am wondering if there is something special I need to do when using the `passphrase` option with `tls.createServer()`

Below are my successful OpenSSL commands for server and client respectively, note that the passphrase.txt file contains a single line that is the passphrase:

```
$ openssl s_server -accept 8888 -cert server.cert -key server.key -pass file:passphrase.txt -CAfile ca.cert
$ openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8888 -cert client.cert -key client.key -pass file:passphrase.txt -CAfile ca.cert
```

I can also make a successful connection if I specify a cipher for the client and/or server with the additional argument of `-cipher 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256'`.  I am using elliptic curve keys generated with `openssl ecparam` and signed with a CA created using `openssl ca` as discussed in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185110/key-generation-requirements-for-tls-ecdhe-ecdsa-aes128-gcm-sha256).

The server code written in node.js looks like this:

```
var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');
var msg = '***********\n\nHello there secure client!\n\n***********';
var port = 8888;
var host = 'localhost'; 

var options = {
    cert : fs.readFileSync('server.cert'),
    key : fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
    passphrase :  (fs.readFileSync('passphrase.txt')).toString(),
    ca : fs.readFileSync('ca.cert'),

//  ciphers: 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256',
//  requestCert : true,
//  rejectUnauthorized : true
};

tls.createServer(options, function(cleartextStream) {
    if (cleartextStream.authorized) {
        console.log('Server-side connection authorized by a Certificate Authority.');
    } else {
        // TODO this code does not appear to get executed even on failed connections
        console.log('Server-side connection not authorized: ' + cleartextStream.authorizationError);
    }

    // send the server message to the client
    cleartextStream.write(msg);
    cleartextStream.setEncoding('utf8');
    cleartextStream.pipe(cleartextStream);
}).listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server started on port: ' + port);
}).on('clientError', function(err){
    console.log('A failed client connection attempt occurred.');
    console.error(err);
    console.log();
});
```

After calling the above code with `node tlsServer.js` and attempting to connect with an OpenSSL client on the command line, I receive the following messages.

SERVER:

```
$ node tlsServer.js
Server started on port: 8888

<< client started here >>

A failed client connection attempt occurred.
[Error: 6396:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher:openssl\ssl\s3_srvr.c:1132:
]
```

CLIENT:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8888 -cert client.cert -key client.key -pass file:passphrase.txt -CAfile ca.cert
CONNECTED(00000003)
2674688:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 320 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

I am using node v0.6.15. And the errors do not change when I uncomment the `ciphers`, `requestCert`, and `rejectUnauthorized` in the options list sent to `tls.createServer()`.  I also have a node.js cersion of the client, and I get a socket hang up code ECONNRESET when I attempt to connect to the node server, and the following error when trying to connect to a OpenSSL server:

```
Connection to localhost:8888 could not be made.
[Error: 6968:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:602:
]
```

Thanks in advance for your help and ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the passphrase is wrong, maybe. Try removing it.

However, [no_shared_cipher](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html) is an error raised when the client can't agree on a cipher suit with the server . Try first removing the cipher suit restriction on the server and seeing what it negotiates to use to isolate the problem.  If this works, then place one with the client and see what happens.

Also, can you check that node is using the same openssl library as the openssl command.

Comment: I will try without a passphrase and see if that works, though I switched to using a file containing the password in both node and openssl to avoid passphrase inconsistencies between the tests.   

My current test is not using a cipher suite restriction - I have it commented out along with the restrictions to reject clients without certs (requireCert and rejectUnauthorized).  So it seems to be rejecting all connections. I removed the commented out lines completely and tried again, but got the same error.   

I will try and find out if my node is using a different version of openssl. Thanks!

Comment: I should also add that `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8888` also gives a hand shake error, and my server previously worked when I was using RSA certs (signed by a local CA) for the server. And I found that the internet was lacking in examples of tls.createServer() that used the ciphers and passphrase options.

Comment: Update, I found the following when calling `process.versions` from node.exe on the windows cmd line `{ node: '0.6.15', v8: '3.6.6.24', ares: '1.7.5-DEV', uv: '0.6', openssl: '0.9.8r' }`, so it looks like my openssl is out of date.

Comment: That might do it. If you supplied Elliptic Curve keys and the system does not support Elliptic curves.

Comment: Due to system constraints I was never able to test with the newer version; I am accepting this answer.